# Best method to check the empty child nodes in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml which is max 3 levels deep. Now by using C# or Xpath what the best method to check the whether all the child nodes under a parent node are empty.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a sample document of:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <baz/>
    <baz>Hello, world!</baz>
    <baz><qux/></baz>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

This expression tells you which children of `foo/bar` have any child elements:

```
foo/bar/*[count(*)>0]
```

This expression tells you which children of `foo/bar` have any child text nodes:

```
foo/bar/*[text()]
```

So to ensure that all children are empty (no child elements or text nodes), ensure that this expression returns true:

```
not(foo/bar/*[count(*)>0 or text()])
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this looks nice and elegant. I more thing will it possible to exclude some child nodes as part of the check.For e.g, there are some nodes which i want to ignore whether they're filled or not.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to exclude, but in general, yes, you can. Feel free to edit your question to elaborate on what you'd like to exclude. :-)

Comment: Chris, you inspired me to learn more about XPath. Thanks to Zvon.org and Google now I understand the power of XPath. Amen!!!!
Thanks again..

Comment: Without XPath, XML would hardly be worth using.

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ to XML query should get close to what you are after:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("contacts",
  new XElement("contact",
    new XAttribute("contactId", ""),
    new XElement("firstName", ""),
    new XElement("lastName", ""),
    new XElement("Address",
        new XElement("Street", ""))
    ),
```

new XElement("contact",
  new XAttribute("contactId", ""),
  new XElement("firstName", ""),
  new XElement("lastName", "")
   )
 );

var query = from c in xml.Elements()
  where c.Value != ""
  select c;

Console.WriteLine(xml);
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());

When the count of the query == 0 you have no elements with content.

Depending on what you are after and if you have no other uses for LINQ style manipulation, the xPath solution posted may well be a better fit.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still in C# 2.0, so don't have the privilege of using LINQ. Will it be possible for you to suggest something else?